# Loopback4 challenges

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am very new to this Loopback 4. When I am setting up my project I am having some setup issues. Below are few things.

1. Environment based datasource loading
    There is no direct way to load the datasource based on the environment.
2. Some configurations/constant variables need to be defined on a JSON file to access into the entire application, again this is also based on the environment.
3. Not able to connect MongoDB Atlas database. In an express application I am able connect, but not in Loopback. Below is the error it is returning.
   url.dbName || self.settings.database,
               ^
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'dbName' of null
4. Not able to achieve model relations.
5. I don't want to return the entire Model in my API response. How can I customize my API response using the Model?
6. I want to write my business logic in a separate file, not in a controller/repository. is it a good idea OR where should I return the business logic? and best practices.

I don't find proper documentation on Loopback4 to solve these issues. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try and help you with a few of these.

1 - You can do env based ds config loading by adding below to the constructor of your datasource.ts file.

```
constructor(
  @inject('datasources.config.pgdb', {optional: true})
  dsConfig: object = config,
) {
  // Override data source config from environment variables
  Object.assign(dsConfig, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    schema: process.env.DB_SCHEMA,
  });
  super(dsConfig);
}
```

After this you can use packages like [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to keep env vars out of your repo.

2 - Use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv). Load dotenv config in application.ts. Add this to the end of application.ts.

```
dotenv.config();
```

You may need to import dotenv like this

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
```

3 - Not sure about this, but check if it is supported in data source generator [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/DataSource-generator.html).

4 - There are currently only 3 type of relations supported. And, in my experience, it's enough for most of the applications - belongsTo, hasMany, hasOne. Refer docs [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Relations.html) for details.

5 - You can return any custom model you want. Just make sure that it extends Entity class from @loopback/repository. Also, make sure you define property types using @property decorator.

6 - You can move your business logic to service classes or create providers as well. We used to keep the DB specific operational logic like custom queries, etc, in the repository and rest of the business logic inside the controller. But if there is a big complex logic, create a provider class and do there. Refer docs for providers [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Creating-components.html#providers).

We also created a boiler plate starter project on github to help community members like you to get a kick start with some of the basic stuff. Most of the above mentioned stuff is implemented there. You can just clone it, change the remote url and all set to go. Take a look [here](https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-starter).